# Append information 'Telephone' tab - Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have tried to add some information in the field 'info' from the tab 'Telephone' in my AD using Powershell.

Here is how I scripted that :

```
ipmo ActiveDirectory
Set-ADUser SAMACCOUNTNAME -Replace @{info="$($_.info) noAGD"}
```

The thing is that it won't work.
However I found the below script around Google which works perfectly :

```
ipmo ActiveDirectory
Import-Csv C:\Users\MyID\Desktop\test.txt | foreach {
    Get-ADUser $_.sAMAccountname -Properties info} | foreach {
       Set-ADUser $_ -Replace @{info="$($_.info) noAGD"
    }
}
```

How come?... Can anyone of you guys clarify that?

Thanks, ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting another answer because, while mine would work, I'd like to explain a bit more about the script you found and why it works and yours doesn't, which I think is your original question.

So, in the script you found, you'll see that it takes information from a CSV file and then pipes (the "|" character) to the Get-ADUser cmdlet (and subsequently the Set-ADUser cmdlet). Where I got tripped up is why it is using two foreach loops. But upon further investigation, I found out why.

When I run just plain:

```
Get-ADUser SAMACCOUNTNAME -Properties info | Set-ADUser -Replace @{info="$($_.info) noAGD"}"
```

It does indeed blank out whatever was in "info" and write " noAGD". However, when I run the same thing, but put my "Set-ADUser" inside a foreach loop, this time including -Identity parameter

```
Get-ADUser SAMACCOUNTNAME -Properties info | foreach { Set-ADUser $_.SamAccountName -Replace @{info="$($_.info) noAGD"}" }
```

It DOES append "noAGD" to what is in there. Pipeline variables and foreach loops have a special relationship, it seems. I know I've run into other instances where I was trying to use the pipeline variable and found that I had to use a foreach loop to make it work.

So in your script, you aren't piping anything and that's why you can't use "$($*.info..." The pipeline variable hasn't been established and "$*" is empty AND there's no foreach loop. When you run your script, the user object should have "[space]noAGD" in it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you post your complete script? As it is, you don't provide a value for SAMACCOUNTNAME. The script you found imports objects into the pipleline from a CSV and pipes it into two foreach loops (which is unnecessary). The better way to write what you found is:

```
Import-Csv C:\Users\MyID\Desktop\test.txt | foreach {Get-ADUser $_.sAMAccountname -Properties info | Set-ADUser $_.SamAccountName -Replace @{info="$($_.info) noAGD"}}
```

To append is a whole different matter and requires variables really. See below:

```
$UsersInfo = Import-Csv C:\Users\MyID\Desktop\test.txt
foreach ($Userinfo in $UsersInfo) {
    $info = Get-ADUser $UserInfo.SamAccountName -Properties Info | Select -ExpandProperty Info
    $info += $Userinfo.info
    Set-ADUser $UserInfo.SamAccountName -Replace @{info="$info noAGD"}
}
```

Without understanding more, that should get you really close.

Comment: Yes, I did. The term 'SAMACCOUNTNAME" was just generic... Your script won't work either though. I just tested it. It replaces the whole information but does not append.

Comment: By the way, some guy checked my post to bring a correction. @Manu, 'information' is always singular in English (just so you know baby).

Comment: Ah, appending is something different. In order to do that, you'd have to capture what's in there first in a variable and append. I will update my answer.